# How to create a datatable using C# from SQL?

Tags: c#, datatable

I need some help with make a datatable from sql.  I'm a Newbie.

I want to make my own datatable from scratch in codebehind and now with the premade that is in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's probably the most basic approach, using a `IDataReader` (in this case, a `SqlDataReader`) to populate a `DataTable`

```
public DataTable MakeDataTable()
{    
    DataTable table = new DataTable();    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Text = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                table.load(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
    return table;  
}
```

Comment: Thanx. But how to run this at program start then? Just remove the public DataTable MakeDataTable() ?

Comment: what do you want to put in the DataTable that needs to be there when the program starts?

Comment: I want the data that is in my database to be showed when I start up the form4.cs That is the all.

Comment: Can't get it to start from Form start. Can you tell me please? This is my form start process. But it's nothing in it here. I want it to be in it but can't find out how.

private void Vis_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
public DataTable MakeDataTable()
{
DataTable table = new DataTable();
Connection string her: =)
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
conn.Open();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
table.Load(rdr);
}
}
}
return table;
}

Comment: ok, your Form has a `load` event. Double-click this in the properties pane to create an EventHandler for the event. Inside of the event handler, put `DataTable table = MakeDataTable();` and then set the data source of whatever control you are using to present the data to the user to be `table`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the `DataTable`.

Try something like this:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(yourQuery, connection))
    {        
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
```